# How do I re-map the changing pane keys in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I want <kbd>Prefix</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd>,<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd> to be mapped to <kbd>Prefix</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>.

I tried:

```
bind-key C-h Left
bind-key C-j Down
bind-key C-k Up
bind-key C-l Right
```

But it didn't really work: it said "Unknown Command: Right". How do I specify this correctly?

I went to `man tmux` to see the command under KEY BINDINGS and it did say Up, Down, Left, Right were the correct command for it. I am confused why the official tmux manual would say those commands when they don't actually exist like that, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `select-pane`:

```
bind C-l select-pane -L
bind C-h select-pane -R
bind C-k select-pane -U
bind C-j select-pane -D
```

Comment: how was I suppose to know I needed `select-pane`?

Comment: @Pinocchio Well, it is in the `man` page, but it is quite a lengthy manual and there are a lot of options covered...